# zabbix - last 3 values of string

Tags: zabbix

I have an Item scanning for the text in a log file which returns "Up".  I want a trigger that if the last 3 times it looks the value isn't "Up" to alert.

Right now I have this:

```
{Template_App_SWIFT:vfs.file.regexp[D:/tmp/snl_status.log,"^Subsystem  Connectivity is  *([A-Z][a-z]*)",,9,9,”\1”].str(Up)}=0
```

However this only captures the most recent value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{Template_App_SWIFT:vfs.file.regexp[D:/tmp/snl_status.log,"^Subsystem  Connectivity is  *([A-Z][a-z]*)",,9,9,”\1”].str("Up",#3)}=0
```

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. Though this might answer the question, please also provide a short explatation what your code actually does and how it solves the initial problem. Do not just drop a line of code without any further description.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`count()`](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/appendix/triggers/functions) trigger function, possibly like so:

```
count(#3, Up, ne)
```